# apt installing more packages than specified as dependencies

Tags: debian, apt, latex

I was trying to install `texmaker` from the repository. For installing the `texlive` I followed the [steps described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75585/install-using-synaptic-ignoring-dependencies). For this the control file I used is [this](http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-control-ex.txt). It has the file texlive-binaries in it.

Then I tried to install `texmaker` from `apt`. It has the dependency listed as

```
# apt-cache depends texmaker
texmaker
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libpoppler-qt4-3
  Depends: libqt4-network
  Depends: libqt4-xml
  Depends: libqtcore4
  Depends: libqtgui4
  Depends: libqtwebkit4
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: zlib1g
  Depends: texmaker-data
  Recommends: aspell
  Recommends: ghostscript
  Recommends: netpbm
  Recommends: psutils
    texlive-local
  Recommends: texlive-latex-extra
    texlive-local
 |Recommends: <hunspell-dictionary>
    myspell-fr
    myspell-ru
    hunspell-an
    hunspell-ar
    hunspell-be
    hunspell-da
    hunspell-de-at
    hunspell-de-at-frami
    hunspell-de-ch
    hunspell-de-ch-frami
    hunspell-de-de
    hunspell-de-de-frami
    hunspell-en-ca
    hunspell-en-us
    hunspell-eu-es
    hunspell-fr
    hunspell-gl-es
    hunspell-hu
    hunspell-kk
    hunspell-ko
    hunspell-ne
    hunspell-ro
    hunspell-ru
    hunspell-se
    hunspell-sh
    hunspell-sr
    hunspell-sv-se
    hunspell-uz
    hunspell-vi
    myspell-et
    myspell-lv
    myspell-pl
 |Recommends: <openoffice.org-spellcheck-de-de>
    hunspell-de-de
    myspell-de-de
 |Recommends: <myspell-dictionary>
    myspell-de-de-oldspell
    myspell-fr
    myspell-ru
    hunspell-kk
    myspell-af
    myspell-bg
    myspell-ca
    myspell-cs
    myspell-da
    myspell-de-at
    myspell-de-ch
    myspell-de-de
    myspell-en-au
    myspell-en-gb
    myspell-en-us
    myspell-en-za
    myspell-eo
    myspell-es
    myspell-et
    myspell-fa
    myspell-fi
    myspell-fo
    myspell-fr-gut
    myspell-ga
    myspell-gd
    myspell-gv
    myspell-he
    myspell-hr
    myspell-hu
    myspell-hy
    myspell-it
    myspell-ku
    myspell-lt
    myspell-lv
    myspell-nb
    myspell-nl
    myspell-nn
    myspell-pl
    myspell-pt-br
    myspell-pt-pt
    myspell-sk
    myspell-sl
    myspell-sw
    myspell-th
    myspell-tl
    myspell-uk
  Recommends: hunspell-en-us
  Recommends: asymptote
  Recommends: ibus-qt4
```

But when I tried to install `texmaker` from `apt` is shows

```
# apt-get install texmaker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  asymptote asymptote-doc ed freeglut3 ibus-qt4 libgraphite3 libibus-qt1
  libptexenc1 libqtwebkit4 libruby1.9.1 libsigsegv2 libyaml-0-2
  python-imaging-tk ruby ruby1.9.1 tex-common texlive-binaries texlive-common
  texmaker-data
```

Why is it so?

I had no problem installing `tex-studio` and `texworks`.

Comment: [Tell apt-get not to install recommends](http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/01/07/howto-tell-apt-get-not-to-install-recommends-packages-in-debian-linux/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As Mikel said, `apt-get` is pulling in the recommends by default. Also, bear in mind that the dependencies have dependencies too, so sometimes you can get extra packages that way.

While recommends are not absolutely necessary, some of the time packagers include as recommends packages that are normally necessary for the correct functioning of the software. The reason that some packages (that are normally necessary for correct functioning) are recommended rather than required is that some users may have special needs which do not require these packages, so this is done so that people with space constraints can keep their systems a little slimmer. It is a flexibility consideration. Debian policy can't be completely precise about this, obviously, so it is a bit of a gray area. Personally, I let `apt-get` install the recommends, and if disk space isn't an issue, that is usually simpler and probably better. But your mileage may vary.

Here is the word from [the Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/index.html)
on [the `Recommends` relationship](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html).

> `Recommends`
>
> This declares a strong, but not absolute, dependency.
>
> The `Recommends` field should list packages that would be found together 
>   with one in all but unusual installations.

Comment: It's mainly a gray area when it gets to graphical environments because they may install a conglomerate of high level front ends that make little sense to be installed by default, but, even then it's unclear because if for example you get the base KDE package, the option while it may install more desktop applications, if unset, it might not let the X server to install all its GPU specific libraries! (if an X wasn't installed)

Comment: @jriv why might not let X servet to install all GPU libraries? Because not all libraries are required? Then it is good, isn't it? seems you suggest the opposite of good, why?