# apt-get without installing recommendations for a certain package

Tags: apt

I can edit

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf
```

and add the line:

```
apt::install-recommends "false";
```

But that will always skip recommendations.

How can I do this only once for the installation to a certain package without changing the config of apt?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77053/4671

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `man 8 apt-get`:

```
   --no-install-recommends
       Do not consider recommended packages as a dependency for installing. Configuration Item: APT::Install-Recommends.
```

Comment: In case I set the config in `apt.conf` I couldn't find an option like `--install-recommends` http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122289/why-is-install-recommends-default-true

Comment: For that you might try:

`apt-get -o apt::install-recommends=true`

Comment: @rubo77 that should be what my command in my previous comment does, overriding the false setting in apt.conf.

Comment: Ah ok, I see... I was too fast in judjing. the option is set with `-o ...` OK thanks